# Making Sure A ShowMessage Stays On Top

Tags: delphi

I have a few applications and I call a ShowMessage('Complete!'); at the end of a long operation.

Most of the time, this works great, but every once in awhile, the Message Dialog will show up behind the main form.

Is there any way for me to ensure the ShowMessage will always be on top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the Windows [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx) API instead and pass in the handle to the active form. Actually, my code uses `Application.MainFormHandle` all the time which I am therefore sure is a reasonable and simple approach.

This will have the benefit of being the system native dialog rather than the home-grown Delphi version.  It supports clipboard operations also.

If you want to get very fancy then you can use the Vista [task dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28VS.85%29.aspx), but that's much more complex and you clearly don't need it for such a simple dialog.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the Application.MainFormHandle comment?  I'm quite familiar with Application.MessageBox:  I was just hoping a quick tweak could be done for ShowMessage.

Comment: One advantage of ShowMessage is that it uses the Task Dialog in never versions of Delphi and the OS.

Comment: @sertac Yes and no. It has a bone-headed test for `ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled` in its decision making process, as if TaskDialogIndirect somehow didn't work in Windows Classic.

Comment: David, can you give me an example of how you use the Application.MainForm.Handle in your application?

Comment: @Orionizer ShowMessage takes a single parameter. It doesn't look terribly tweakable. I don't know which version of Delphi you use (may be relevant), but I'd guess Application.MessageBox would solve your problem, and it handles the owner window handle issue for you. I'd still just call Win32 MessageBox directly, via a wrapper to allow easy changes in the future.

Comment: @Orionizer It's the first parameter to [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh, so you don't mean calling Application.MessageBox?  I would assume this would perform the same thing except automatically passing the MainForm.Handle for you.  Also, I'm using D7 (Unfortunately, I still have Win9x machines that have to run my software).

Comment: @Orionizer I think calling Application.MessageBox in D7 would be fine, and essentially equivalent. It goes to some trouble to make sure that the dialog appears on the same monitor as the currently active form.

Comment: @Orionizer My main advice would be to wrap up all calls to show such dialogs in your own routines to give you a single piece of code to work with if you wanted to re-route them at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks David!  I appreciate your advice!